# Unset a single item form a php array embedded in a html site with JS button

Tags: javascript, php, html

My question is. I want to press that `remove` button at the end and remove my item form the session.

how can i do this?

**js:**

```
$('.remove button') .click (function() {
removeItem(This);
});
```

**PHP and HTML:**

```
   <?php
  foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $item) {
  $data = getProducts($pdo, $item);
  if ($data["ColorName"] == NULL) {
      $color = "";
  } else {
      $color = "Color: ".$data["ColorName"]."<br>";
  }
  if ($data["Size"] == "") {
      $size = "";
  } else {
      $size = "Size: ".$data["Size"]."<br>";
  }
  print("<div class=\"basket-product\">
    <div class=\"item\">
      <div class=\"product-image\">
        <img src=\"http://placehold.it/120x166\" alt=\"Placholder Image 2\" class=\"product-frame\">
      </div>
      <div class=\"product-details\">
        <h1><strong><span class=\"item-quantity\">1</span> x ".$data["StockItemName"]."</strong></h1>
        <p><strong>".$color." ".$size."</strong></p>
        <p>Product Code - ".$data["StockItemID"]."</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=\"price\">".$data["RecommendedRetailPrice"]."</div>
    <div class=\"quantity\">
      <input type=\"number\" value=\"1\" min=\"1\" class=\"quantity-field\">
    </div>
    <div class=\"subtotal\">". $data["RecommendedRetailPrice"] * 1 ."</div>
    <div class=\"remove\">
      <button>Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>");
  }
```

I tried using `Unset` in allot of places, but that doesn't seem to get working :')

Comment: so the `$_SESSION["cart"]` is an array object right? do you want to remove a single item from it with the remove button or unset the whole session variable?

Comment: yes the     $_SESSION["cart"]    s an array.
i just want to remove 1 item from the session using that button. it's a cart for a webshop. so inmagine multiple items in your cart and then you want to remove 1 item when you got for example like 3 different items in there

Answer (score 1):

:)

The solution is rather easy, but requires some explanation in order to be understood.

What you need here is to:

1. Create a new php file, which would fetch the post data (in this case ID of an element) and then simply unset the key (sub-array), which contains the cart item you want to remove.
   You can use `$key_to_remove = array_search($_POST['stock_item_id'], array_column($_SESSION["cart"], 'StockItemID'));` and then simply unset it `unset($_SESSION["cart"][$key_to_remove]);`
2. Assign `id="remove_<?php echo $data["StockItemID"]; ?>"` to the `<div class="basket-product">` and `data-product-id="<?php echo $data["StockItemID"]; ?>"` to the button, so you can identify it for item removal via javascript/jquery and you need that value extracted later for the item you want to remove from the corresponding session array (which is, in this case, `$_SESSION["cart"]`).
3. Create a callback function for removal `on('click', function(){});`
4. Inside that function extract that value `data-product-id` from the button you just clicked `var stock_item_id=$(this).attr('data-product-id');`
5. Inside the same function, after step 4, create an ajax call to the file from step 1 with the post data from step 4
6. On successful execution of an ajax call, delete the corresponding product row you have marked with `id="remove_<?php echo $data["StockItemID"]; ?>"` in step 2 with the following code `$("#remove_"+stock_item_id).remove();`

In the end, your code would look like this

**YOUR INITIAL PHP AND HTML** (With small corrections)

```
<?php 
 foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $item) {
     $data = getProducts($pdo, $item);
     if ($data["ColorName"] == NULL) {
        $color = "";
     } else {
        $color = "Color: ".$data["ColorName"]."<br>";
     }
    if ($data["Size"] == "") {
        $size = "";
    } else {
        $size = "Size: ".$data["Size"]."<br>";
    }
 ?>
 <div class="basket-product">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="product-image">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120x166" alt="Placholder Image 2" class="product-frame">
        </div>
        <div class="product-details">
            <h1>
                <strong>
                    <span class="item-quantity">
                        1
                    </span>
                    x <?php echo $data["StockItemName"]; ?>
                </strong>
            </h1>
            <p>
                <strong>
                    <?php echo $color." ".$size; ?>
                </strong>
            </p>
            <p>
                Product Code - <?php echo $data["StockItemID"]; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        <?php echo $data["RecommendedRetailPrice"]; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="quantity">
        <input type="number" value="1" min="1" class="quantity-field">
    </div>
    <div class="subtotal">
        <?php echo $data["RecommendedRetailPrice"]; ?> * 1
    </div>
    <div class="remove">
        <button data-product-id="<?php echo $data["StockItemID"]; ?>">
            Remove
        </button>
    </div>
 </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove button').on('click', function() {
        var stock_item_id=$(this).attr('data-product-id');

        $.ajax({
            url: "new_php_file_created_to_remove_item_from_session_via_ajax.php",
            data: 
                {stock_item_id : stock_item_id}
        }).done(function() {
            $("#remove_"+stock_item_id).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

**NEW PHP FILE (new_php_file_created_to_remove_item_from_session_via_ajax.php)**

```
<?php
    $stock_item_id = $_POST['stock_item_id'];
    $key_to_remove = array_search($_POST['stock_item_id'], array_column($_SESSION["cart"], 'StockItemID'));
    unset($_SESSION["cart"][$key_to_remove]);

    if(isset($_SESSION["cart"][$key_to_remove])) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

For the sake of readability and further maintenance and possible additions, I would strongly recommend you to separate php, html and js code into separate files, but that's only a suggestion. :)